# PowerBi Line chart with total

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart, measure

I am finding it impossible to do what I want: a Line chart that has a line for each category and a line with the total of all the categories.

[Demo file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TG1AwPaJJUs1frvCZP7PQKFvMAJPWzZW/view?usp=sharing)

This is my setup:
[image]

I am aware that I can create a measure for each category and a measure for the total and put all of these measures in the values field while removing the legend.

However, this kills the entire point of the slicer.

I need the slicer to remain functional, that is to say it allows the user to add/remove lines for each category but the line for Total must ALWAYS be visible.

The measure for each category method is NOT good. In future, more categories can be added, therefore the requirement for manually creating a new measure for these new categories is a no-go.

So, how can I get my total line while retaining the slicer functionality without manually creating measures? I assume there is a dynamic measure possible...

Comment: I have tried it out, it is the restriction in PowerBi, where `legend` is added, you can only drag single value to the field, not even `secondary axis`, however you can drag `multiple value` to a field by creating all the comparison measure you need when `legend is blank`, although it is tedious process and not `dynamic.

Comment: You don't need a measure per category, just add one measure for the total that ignores the filter context of everything but the week using ALLEXCEPT

Comment: @Jon If I do what you suggest then I don't get the lines for the individual categories.